# Eclipse making background video skip with almost every click of the mouse

Tags: windows-7, eclipse

The problem is i like to listen to videos online (mostly or all flash video) while programming and never had any problems until i started using eclipse, now every time i do just about anything other than type, it makes the video skip/freeze really bad and is really annoying. I have never had this happen using visual studio, netbeans, or adobe flash for that matter, unless i was compiling or doing something that hogs the processor.

Are there any settings that might could fix this its getting really annoying. it happens almost every time i even click "find" on the find pop-up window and it is not like it is having to search a big file or anything it is only 700 lines, with honestly only about 1/2 that have content on them. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? I haven't had videos playing at the same time, but if you're using Juno, I've noticed that it definitely has more lags (for example, while editing code or moving internal windows) than the 3.x versions (often enough that I'm considering rolling back to 3.8).

Comment: 4.2,  not sure its code name

Comment: The codename for 4.2 is Juno.

Comment: so nothing i can really do then unless i want to start all over with a 3.x?

Comment: I don't know. There are various options for tuning Eclipse (for example, by upping the memory allocated to it in `eclipse.ini`), which might help. It might be worthwhile installing a 3.8 somewhere just to try out.

Comment: stackoverflow has lots of Eclipse tuning questions/answers, if you're inclined, but I'm not optimistic, since whatever it's doing is affecting your video player process.

Comment: i started this in stackoverflow someone suggested i post it here for better results. I'll try the .ini file tuning thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is precisely as you mentioned:

> I have never had this happen using visual studio, netbeans, or adobe flash for that matter, unless i was compiling or doing something that hogs the processor.

Eclipse by default compiles automatically in the background. You can disable this behavior from the <kbd>Build</kbd> menu: make sure <kbd>Build automatically</kbd> is disabled.

Personally, I prefer automatic building, but I can understand that on older machines it may make things sluggish. Alternatively, if you have a multi-core processor, you may want to consider giving Eclipse core affinity.